# Why can't I import numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to import numpy. I downloaded numpy compatible with python 2.7 (which is what is running on my mac 10.8). Before I did so, I created a python script called "numpy.py". Now, whenever I "import numpy" in a new script, it runs the script called "numpy.py" even after I have deleted that script. What do I do? How can I check to see if numpy was downloaded properly?

Comment: Do you still have a `numpy.pyc`?

Comment: Adding to jon's comment, .pyc files are usually hidden by default

Comment: The collections module lets you do `import collections` then `print collections.__file__` and it says which file it was loaded from. I don't know if numpy does, but it might be worth trying `print numpy.__file__`

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler that's Python generally, not `collections` specifically.

Comment: @saraccina then try deleting that, too! Python can still `import` from these bytecode-compiled files.

Comment: @jonrsharpe It doesn't work for `itertools` ...

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler that's because `itertools` is implemented in C (in CPython), not pure Python. It's therefore not imported from a Python file, so the `__file__` attribute isn't set.

Comment: @TimCastelijns Replying to "it works for one" and saying "that's Python generally" sounds like a claim that it will work for any module. If, in fact, it works for some and not others depending on some implementation details you don't know from merely using the module" we're no further forward than saying "try it with numpy it might work".

Comment: So delete anything python.pyc?

Comment: yes, delete numpy.pyc. Other way (if the purpose is checking your numpy distribution) is to use an alias for a numpy module: `import numpy as np; a = np.version.version`